# How do I POST data into MongoDB database using node.JS?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, forms, post

the code below is pretty messy so don't judge too much! I am trying to POST a basic user profile into my database, i don't think i am far off but i keep getting a 404.

im pretty knew to all of these technologies so could somebody please enlighten me as to what i have done wrong.

node.js POST method

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/local';

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('signIn', { title: 'signIn' });
});

router.get('/getData', function(req, res, next){
    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {

        assert.equal(null, error);
        var cursor = db.collection('userData').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(doc, err){
            assert.equal(null, err);
            resultArray.push(doc);
        }, function() {
            db.close();
            res.render('index', {items: resultArray});
        } );
    });
});

router.post ('/insert', function(req,res,next) {
    var item = {
        email: req.body.email,
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection('userData').insertOne(item, function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('item has been inserted');
            db.close;
        });
    });

    res.redirect('/');
});
module.exports = router;
```

form HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


    <title>SignIn Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/signIn.css"/>


</head>

<body>

<div class="background">


<div class="loginFormWrapper">
    <form action="/users/submit" method="POST">
        <div class="loginForm">
            <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="first name">

            <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="last name">

            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

    </form>
    <form action="users" method="GET">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">get result</button>
    </form>
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
    var express = require('express');

    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var validate = require('form-validate');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');




    var index = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var About = require('./routes/about');
    var signIn = require('./routes/signIn');
    var contact = require('./routes/contact');


    var app = express();




    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/users', users);
    app.use('/About', About);
    app.use('/signIn', signIn);
    // app.use('/contact', contact);







//catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
 });

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require("mongoose");
var router = express.Router();


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting?

Comment: var url? that is the default setup for mongodb. in the post and get methods i am connecting to that database through url.... my code is an amalgamation of different tutorials so some var names may be odd!

Comment: I meant URL like localhost:3000/users/something that kind of URL. You said you are getting 404 but you did not mention the URL address

Comment: oh sorry, yeah this > http://localhost:3000/users/submit

Comment: Post your routes/users.js file

Answer (score 5):

A quick reminder, the post() method just gets the data from the `<form>` you specify. For you to be able to get that data you'd have to do something like this.

app.js

```
const express = require('express)
const mongoose = require('mongoose)

var app = express()

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:"yourPortHere"/"mongoDBhere"')
```

Now post needs the body parser in order to be able to retrieve the data and sort of "translate it" to JS, for that you need the body parser.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})) //Post Body Parser
```

Now let's get to the post

```
app.post("/action", (req, res) => {
var userData = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
}
```

For the moment userData is going to hold the data you just retrieved from the `<form>`
Remember that `action="/YourActionHere` is the identifier for the `app.post("/YourActionHere")` so those two have to match, otherwise you will not get the data.

To save it to MongoDB you first need to create a model of the object you want to store, if MongoDB has a Database named **movies** with a directory named **films** on it you first have to create a Model named **film** since mongoose will save it in the directory **films** (<- By directory I mean collection)

So: in folder Models you create a model of the object

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
var film = new Schema({
title: String,
year: String,
director: String 
 })
module.exports = mongoose.model("movie", movieSchema)
```

To be able to use that new Schema you have to import it in you app.js with

```
var Film = require('pathToFilmSchema')
```

Now in your post you will save userData to that Schema, and mongoose will store it in the collection specified in its .js.

```
app.post("/action", (req, res) => {
 var userData = {
    title: req.body."name",
    year: req.body."name",
    director: req.body.""
}
new Film(userData)
})
```

If the structure is the same de Data in that variable will be stored in a Schema, then you just have to call the method `.save()`, which you can call right after like this

```
newFil(userData)
.save()
```

Now mongoose will store a new object with film Schema into the database you have connected at the top. Keep in mind that, if you don't have a collection named film mongoDB will create one collection named **films** (the plural, always) and store the Schema there.

After saving you can `res.redirect()` to "/" or render another page, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have posted to url `users/submit` but i don't see any API for `users/submit` . You have said to use users for `/users` urls but have you defined the `/submit` within `/users`?

You could go through this 
[Routing in expressjs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: ill have a read of that, thanks. i think its clear that i dont understand routing very well

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `app.post` function you should have something like this:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let connectionUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
// or
// let connectionUrl = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<your-cluster-url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

// creating the message object
let obj = {"text" : "Something"};

console.log("OBJ: " + obj);

MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    // if database and collection do not exist they are created
    
    var db = client.db('YourDatabase')
    
    db.collection("YourCollection").insertOne(obj, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 message inserted");
        client.close();
    });
});
```